# Php Post to two tables in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to POST to two tables at the same time. I'm trying to get the `DonorID` to display in to another table under `$description`. I'm able to just write any text in the `$description`, but I need it to be dynamic not static, which is what the text is. I have two tables; the first is `accounting` and the second is `donations`. I'm trying to alter the `$description='Donation from Donor';` and have the donor that made the transaction be listed where the Donor is. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

  $dbserver = "localhost";
  $dblogin = "root";
  $dbpassword = "";
  $dbname = "";

  $date=$_POST['date'];
  $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
  $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
  $middleinitial=$_POST['middleinitial'];
  $organization=$_POST['organization'];
  $donorid=$_POST['donorid'];
  $paymenttype=$_POST['paymenttype'];
  $nonmon=$_POST['nonmon'];
  $event=$_POST['event'];
  $Income=$_POST['Income'];
  $account='Revenue';
  $description='Donation from Donor';
  $transactiontype='Income';
  $Expense='0.00';

  $con = mysql_connect("$dbserver","$dblogin","$dbpassword");
    if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect to the mySQL server please contact technical support 
           with the following information: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  mysql_select_db("$dbname", $con);


  $sql = "INSERT INTO donations (date, firstname, middleinitial, lastname, 
            organization, donorid, paymenttype, nonmon, Income, event)  

  Values        
            ('$date','$firstname','$middleinitial','$lastname','$organization',  
             '$donorid','$paymenttype','$nonmon','$Income','$event')";


  $sql2 = "INSERT INTO accounting (date, transactiontype, account, 
              description, Income, Expense)

  VALUES ('$date','$transactiontype','$account','$description','$Income','$Expense')";

  mysql_query($sql2);


    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {

    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }
  echo "1 record added";

  mysql_close($con);

  header( 'Location: http://localhost/donations.php' ) ;
  ?>
```

Comment: you are not executing query `$sql` also i would not use `mysql_` for new project, please switch to `mysqli` or `PDO`

Answer (score 2):

As i said i would personaly use `mysqli` for new project, here a sample of you code with mysqli:

```
       $dbserver = "localhost";
       $dblogin = "root";
       $dbpassword = "";
       $dbname = "";

       $date=$_POST['date'];
       $firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
       $lastname=$_POST['lastname'];
       $middleinitial=$_POST['middleinitial'];
       $organization=$_POST['organization'];
       $donorid=$_POST['donorid'];
       $paymenttype=$_POST['paymenttype'];
       $nonmon=$_POST['nonmon'];
       $event=$_POST['event'];
        $Income=$_POST['Income'];
       $account='Revenue';
       $description='Donation from Donor';
       $transactiontype='Income';
       $Expense='0.00';

        //opening connection
        $mysqli = new mysqli($dbserver, $dblogin, $dbpassword, $dbname);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
        {
            printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
            exit();
        }

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `donations` (`date`, `firstname`, `middleinitial`, `lastname`, `organization`, `donorid`, `paymenttype`, `nonmon`, `Income`, `event`) Values  ('$date','$firstname','$middleinitial','$lastname','$organization', '$donorid','$paymenttype','$nonmon','$Income','$event')";

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `accounting` (`date`, `transactiontype`, `account`, `description`, `Income`, `Expense`) VALUES ('$date','$transactiontype','$account','$description','$Income','$Expense')";

        $query1 = $mysqli->query($sql) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
        $query2 = $mysqli->query($sql2) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

        //closing connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        header( 'Location: http://localhost/donations.php' ) ;
```

`UPDATE`
you can add donorid simply placing both vars in the query like:

```
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO `accounting` (`date`, `transactiontype`, `account`, `description`, `Income`, `Expense`) VALUES ('".$date."','".$transactiontype."','".$account."','".$donorid . " " . $description."','".$Income."','".$Expense."')";
```

this way i just separate `donorid` and `description` with a space but you can add anything you want to in plain text:

```
'".$donorid . " - " . $description."'
```

Comment: OK, I've made the change, but do you have a suggestion on getting the donorid to appear in the description?

Comment: Yes i'm going to change my answer

Answer (score 0):

After this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO donations (date, firstname, middleinitial, lastname, 
        organization, donorid, paymenttype, nonmon, Income, event)  

        Values        
        ('$date','$firstname','$middleinitial','$lastname','$organization',  
         '$donorid','$paymenttype','$nonmon','$Income','$event')";
```

put

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

Please execute the query.

Comment: Ok, I added the mysql_query($sql); but how to do I make the Description dynamic and make sure that the donorid gets put there? What syntax would I Use?

Comment: then you to run a select query on donor id and then use that donation id and add it to your decription variable.

Answer (score 0):

Things I see is ..

First your just executing your `$sql2` but not the other `$sql` statement

Another is while inserting you declared some columns name that is a mysql reserved word (`date` column)

you should have `` backticks for them..

Refer to this link [MYSQL RESEERVED WORDS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/reserved-words.html)

*additional note: Your query is also vulnerable to sql injection*

[SQL INJECTION](http://bobby-tables.com/)

[How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: I've done a bit of research on SQL Injection.. i've ran the '); drop table donations ; -- and nothing happened. Except that it said that there was a Mysql error statement. Can you show me what type of injection I'm vulnerable to?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split $sql2 to 2

1st :-

```
 $sql2 = "INSERT INTO accounting (description) SELECT * FROM donations WHERE donorid='$donorid'"
```

then another one

```
"UPDATE accounting SET date='', transactiontype='', account ='', Income='', Expense ='' WHERE description=(SELECT * FROM donations WHERE donorid='$donorid')"
```

that will take all the information from donoation for the given donorid and list it under description in accounting

Answer (score 0):

Just write after insert on trigger on first table to insert data into another table.